# 2D layout problem with RL - questions about state representation

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-rl

I want to solve the following sort of problem with RL, specifically Q-learning (using the tensorflow-agents library):

The input is a polygon $\mathcal{P}$ and a list of rectangle sizes $\mathcal{L}=\{s_{1}=[h_1,w_1],s_2=[h_2,w_2],\ldots,s_k=[h_k,w_k]\}$. It is required to place polygons of the sizes given in $\mathcal{L}$ inside $\mathcal{P}$ without overlap. Each configuration is scored at the end of the episode according to the placed rectangles' total area and some other criteria which are immaterial at the moment.

My problem is how to represent the problem in a way that allows for generalization. My first approach was to discretize the polygon $\mathcal{P}$ and to define an action = (rectangle placement) as a triple $(x_{TL}, y_{TL}, i \in \{1,\ldots,k\})$ and to train a DQN agent. But this approach forces me to train a separate agent for each instance $(\mathcal{P},\mathcal{L})$ which is woefully inefficient and very unsatisfying.

So what I am looking for is a way to somehow:

(1) encode the state/observation in a fixed-length representation

(2) encode the action space in a fixed-lenght representation

while

(3) taking into account the fact that part of the action is choosing a placement point in $\mathcal{P}$

I thought about handling (1) by training an autoencoder that takes as input a, say, $299x299$ image of $\mathcal{P}$ with a number of polygons drawn inside it and learns an internal code of length, say, $100$. But I fail to see how to handle (2) and (3) with this approach.

Any suggestions or pointers will be greatly appreciated.